# Saving .doc files with MS Word through WebDAV not possible - no PUT request sent

Tags: node.js, ms-word, webdav, libreoffice-writer

I'm trying to implement a Node.js file server using the [webdav-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdav-server) npm module which works perfectly.

I'm able to open, edit and save **.docx** files with Microsoft Word (Microsoft® Word 2016 MSO (16.0.14228.20216) 32-Bit). As well as **.odt** files with LibreOffice Writer (Version: 7.0.6.2 (x64))

Capturing the requests made by Microsoft Word or LibreOffice Writer I detect the expected order GET - LOCK - PUT - UNLOCK representing the requests made by opening a file (GET), deactivating the readonly mode (LOCK), saving some changes (PUT) and closing the text editor application (UNLOCK).

[image: Traffic editing saving a .docx file with word]

---

However if I want to edit and save a **.doc** file with my Mircosoft Word application I see that there is not PUT request when saving the changes and therefore the changes are lost on closing the application. There is no feedback of any kind through MS Word when clicking the save button. Not that it saved the changes nor that it didn't.

[image: Traffic editing saving a .doc file with word]

---

On the other hand when I open the **.doc** files with LibreOffice Writer there is a PUT request as I'd expected it to be.

I also tried to switch the file type in the MS Word settings so it should use **.doc** to save files instead of **.docx** (default with MS Word 2016) but that didn't change anything.

Anyone knows what the problem could be? I don't get why the PUT request should not be sent by Microsoft Word for the .doc file type but for the .docx file type?

(It's a requirement of the project that it also works with **.doc** files, in the best case with LibreOffice and MS Word)

Thank you all in advance!